# Invalid Stack Name Error Create Stack Portainer API

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, portainer

I'm trying to create a new Stack from a file using the Portainer API.
I'm using a docker-compose file and I am trying to set the name of the stack and pass it as data to the request.

My goal is it to run this code in a python script. This is my current Python script:

```
import requests
import json

class PortainerAPI:
    def __init__(self,url,stackName):
        self.url = url
        self.stackName = stackName
        self.bearerToken = self.authorize()
        self.stackID = self.getStacks()
        
    # authorization, get Bearer Token
    def authorize(self):
        payload = json.dumps({
          "password": "pwd_Admin",
          "username": "mes"
        })
        headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", self.url+'/auth', headers=headers, data=payload)
        bearerToken = json.loads(response.text)
        bearerToken = bearerToken["jwt"]
        return(bearerToken)

    # create new stack
    def createStack(self):
        payload={'Name': self.stackName}
        files=[
          ('file',('docker-compose-apache.yml',open('docker-compose-apache.yml','rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
        ]
        headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': self.bearerToken
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", self.url+'/stacks?type=2&method=file&endpointId=2', headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
        return(response.text)
    
    # remove Stack
    def removeStack(self):
        payload={}
        headers = {
          'Authorization': self.bearerToken
        }

        response = requests.request("DELETE", url+'/stacks/'+str(self.stackID)+'?external=true&endpointId=2', headers=headers, data=payload)

        print(response.text)
    
    # get StackID
    def getStacks(self):
        payload={}
        headers = {
          'Accept': '*/*',
          'Authorization': self.bearerToken
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url+'/stacks', headers=headers, data=payload)
        
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        try:
            stackObject = list(filter(lambda x:x["Name"]==self.stackName,data))
            stackID = stackObject[0]['Id']
            return(stackID)
        except:
            print("Can't found stackName")
        
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    url = "http://XX.XXX.XXX.X:9000/api"
    stackName = 'test'
    
    test = PortainerAPI(url,stackName)
    print(test.createStack())
```

If I run this script I get the following output:

```
{"message":"Invalid request payload","details":"Invalid stack name"}
```

Although if I am executing the request in Postman or with Curl, I don't get this error.
This is the curl script I'm using:

```
curl.exe -X 'POST' `
  'http://XX.XXX.XXX.X:9000/api/stacks?type=2&method=file&endpointId=2' `
  -H 'accept: application/json' `
  -H "Authorization: $BearerToken" `
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' `
  -F 'Name=($stackName)' `
  -F 'EndpointID=$endpointID' `
  -F 'file=@apache-dc.yml'
```

Can anybody help me here to get my python script up and running?! Thank you very much in advance!